# How to find JSON entries based on user?

Tags: mongodb, react-native, express, mongoose, axios

In a MERN iOS react-native app, how could I query for the correct JSON entries in Mongodb atlas based on the user thats logged in (ie email)? A basic feature. For a concrete example, find how much the logged in user (email) read that day (minutesRead), and send it back to them in the frontend of the mobile app. Heres the relevant code:

At sign in, they fill in the following (mongoose schema):

```
/* user.model.js */
const userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            trim: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
            minlength: 6,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Now, when in app after sign in, they can fill in the following entries (mongoose schema):

```
/* log.model.js */
const logSchema = new Schema(
    {
        minutesRead: {
            type: number,
            required: true,
        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            required: true,
        },
    },    
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);
const Log = mongoose.model("Log", logSchema);
```

Here is my route for logging the minutesRead:

```
const Log = require("../models/log.model");

router.route("/add").post((req, res) => {
    const minutesRead = req.body.minutesRead;
    // ..etc

    const newLog = new Log({ minutesRead, /* ..etc */ });

    newLog.save().then(() => res.json("Log added")).catch(error => //throw error);
}
```

And now show the logged in user's specific minutesRead data in the frontend:

```
/* Home.js screen */
const url = "http://localhost....";

const home = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [totalMinutesRead, setMinutes] = React.useState("");

    axios.get(url).then(response => {
       setMinutes(() => { 
           /* sum all of user's minutesRead entries in a loop here */
       });
    });

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{totalMinutesRead}</Text>
        </View>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to know which log is from which user.

The best way to do this in my opinion is to add a **user** field in the **logSchema:**

```
user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}]
```

In your

> route for logging the minutesRead

You need to pass the user's id in the body.

Then, to get the **totalMinutesRead** you'll have to do something like this to filter by the user's id.

```
router.route('getTotalMinutes/:user').get(async (req, res) => {
    const logs = await Log.find({ user: req.params.user });

    const totalMinutes = logs.reduce((total, log) => total + log.minutesRead, 0);

    res.json({ totalMinutes });
}
```

Finally in react-native make sure you pass your user's id in the url.

Comment: So the backend should do the summing calculation for minutesRead (in the example) ? Currently i have the frontend as you can see. How does the frontend then access the totalMinutes for res.json({totalMinutes}) ?

Comment: You can do it either on the frontend or the backend, this is up to you. If you do it on the backend, in the front you can do setMinutes to response.totalMinutes. If you want to do it in the front, then you have to pass all the documents, so res would be something like res.json({ data: logs })

Comment: Thanks Nacho, however it still isnt working. I think the issue is that i dont understand why i would "pass the user's id in the body" when they (the actual user of app) are not entering that data in the frontend. They are never prompted for that information. If i console.log() that variable when i do try, its undefined, as i would expect. Im assuming by this ofcourse you mean `const user = req.body.user` in the `router.route('/add').post()` section.

Comment: You can get the user's ID in the response when they log in. Another way is to use the user's email. In your `logSchema`: `email: { type: string }`. Then in `getTotalMinutes`: `const logs = await Log.find({ email: req.params.user  })`